# TensorFlow Serving and serving more models than the memory can allow

Tags: tensorflow-serving

TensorFlow Serving can serve multiple models by configuring the `--model_config_file` command line argument. I had success using this feature in small experiments.

However, it's unclear to me what happens when the total memory required by these models is larger than, say, the available GPU memory.

Does the server just crash? Or does it support keeping a subset of models available and possibly unloading/loading models based on the usage?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Trying to load a model when you are out of memory will fail to load that model. There's no dynamic loading/unloading at this time.

Answer (score 2):

As currently written, it will crash if there isn't enough memory for all of the models requested to load. Internally there is a feature to gracefully decline to load a model that doesn't fit, which you could enable by writing a small PR that pipes the ServerCore::Options::total_model_memory_limit_bytes option [1] to a flag in main.cc. Note, however, that the notion of "fitting in memory" is based on a somewhat crude way of estimating model RAM footprint.

As Gautam said, it does not dynamically load/unload, although there is a library implemented for that (which isn't currently used in the released binary), called CachingManager [2].

[1] https://github.com/tensorflow/serving/blob/master/tensorflow_serving/model_servers/server_core.h#L112

[2] https://github.com/tensorflow/serving/blob/master/tensorflow_serving/core/caching_manager.h

Comment: Thanks for the details. For [2], are there plans to integrate this behavior in the open source `tensorflow_model_server` client?